# Database Design and Performance : mySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have made an image for this question:
[Database design http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/9363/37759585.png](http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/9363/37759585.png)

What is the right design? All site's block inserting in only one table or separate tables?

Comment: It's hard to see what you're asking about.  Can you provide more detail?

Comment: Of course;
Design a huge table or separate site's blocks in different tables?

Comment: For example: left block: references, right block : blah blah

Comment: That answer does not help at all. Are you talking about sections of some screen?

Comment: @Scott Saunders;
I think that the image is clear. (its my opinion of course)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use separate tables if you really care about performance in this case. Each table should include atomic information relevant to the specific object, so it would be better to have one table for articles and the second one for categories.

Comment: Categories and articles are in different tables. Consider a news portal: News, headlines, spot news. What about this issue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how you'll be accessing the information.

If you're performing queries across many categories it may make sense to include all the categories in a single table.  If your queries will only operating across a single query at a time, you're probably better off breaking the categories out into different tables.